# How can we `git stash apply` to move between all states of the repo?

Tags: git, git-stash

For example, if we have one simple solution in our code, we could

```sh
git stash save "Simple solution"
```

and now we are all "clean" and can try another solution.  But just to experiment, I did a

```sh
git stash apply stash@{0}
```

to see that the simple solution is working.  Now, can I `git stash apply` to go back to the "clean" state?  It seems we can go to any of the `git stash` state by `git stash apply stash@{0}`, `git stash apply stash@{1}`, etc, but how can we go back to the "clean" state without needing to save another stash?

Comment: Either `git checkout -f HEAD` or `git reset --hard HEAD` will do.

Comment: I was hoping to work with `git stash` during this process. So `git stash` cannot do it without creating a new stash I think?

Comment: As per @adrian-j-moreno's answer, it's easy to make 'feature'/'fix', etc _branches_ from the main branch (up-to-date) first, so that you can work independently on different solutions and then decide whicih one you use (_merge_) : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

Comment: You were hoping to fill a hole with a drill? Drill a hole with paste?  Use the right tool for the job, Git's a toolbox and also just one toolbox in a larger kit. There are not points for purity if you build an entire house with just a nail puller.

Comment: @jthill are you saying `git stash` is good for a temporary push and pop type of operation, instead of having 2 or 3 versions and try which version is the best?

Comment: No, I was responding to you wanting to do everything that needs doing with just the one tool. `git stash apply` to apply a stash to the working tree and index, `git reset --hard` to clear changes from your working tree and index, regardless of source. There's already a tool that does what you want. Drill holes with one tool, fill them with another. And you can fill holes regardless of what made them, Construction work is not known for looking particularly tidy, no matter how organized the chaos is underneath.

Comment: that's what I felt about `git`. It is like using Assembly language to do version control. Some other tools may present it more like `set snapshot 1`, `set snapshot 2`, `set snapshot original` and it is an interface for accomplish a specific task. It is like we don't control the temperature of a refrigerator by altering the voltage and current and condenser level. We only turn a knob.

Comment: But now you're not complaining about what the tools do, but that there's only one tool to do exactly the same task in different contexts. You're asking for a hammer to drive nails for doors and another hammer you want called by a more pleasing name that drives nails for walls, even though they're the exact same task in a different context. That way lies duplication of effort and the inconsistency that brings. The pieces would be better, the whole would be worse.

Comment: even in software design, there is talk about giving out a good interface.  Git is famous for users having to deal with the plumbing. It is not about a hammer. It is about a higher level operation vs a plumbing operation

Comment: But sanding down a surface is not a high level operation. Neither is cleaning changes out  of a work tree. When that's what you want to do, there's a tool for it.

Comment: I think you don't get it. It is not about the tool.  If you keep on mentioning tool, you can justify "why would you put on a screw by a hammer" and make it sound reasonable.  The key here is about wanting to set the refrigerator temperature and you don't turn a knob but have to open up a panel and adjust the condenser valve

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to look into the [git flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) approach. This page also links to a few other git workflows. You're trying to stash changes when you should be collecting changes into a feature branch to verify the approach.

> Instead of a single main branch, this workflow uses two branches to
> record the history of the project. The main branch stores the
> official release history, and the develop branch serves as an
> integration branch for features. It's also convenient to tag all
> commits in the main branch with a version number.

[image: main and develop branches]

> Each new feature should reside in its own branch, which can be pushed
> to the central repository for backup/collaboration. But, instead of
> branching off of main, feature branches use develop as their parent
> branch. When a feature is complete, it gets merged back into develop.
> Features should never interact directly with main.

[image: feature branches]

Comment: so you are saying, if it is to compare 2, 3 methods of doing it (solving a problem), we should use branches, instead of stash. A stash is more like a temporary thing for user to push and pop. It is not meant for arbitrary access like "use v1", "use v3", "use v2"

Comment: @kla yes, `git stash` is meant to temporarily _stash_ (see?) changes away and then get them back. "use 1, 2, 3" is exactly what branches are for: each branch tracks a different version/variation of your solution. In the end, you can delete all branches which turned out to be useless.

Comment: I see. So `git stash` is more convenient, because it allows quick switching. And then `git branch` is more capable, except it is more troublesome, because we have to commit all files, and then `git checkout` the last server pull version, and then `git checkout -b solution02`... so if there is a mix of `stash` and `branch`, that would be nice.  I am not sure if `git worktree` is for that, but last time I checked, it actually created extra directories in the main directory

Comment: @kla maybe I've been using Git for too long, but I don't see much advantage in using `git stash save` + `git stash apply stash@{…}` vs `git add -u; git commit` + `git checkout branchname`. What problem are you trying to solve exactly? Maintaining multiple version/variations in parallel? => branches. Putting stuff aside so you can temporarily do something else, then returning to your previous changes? => stashes.

Comment: @knittl so to have 3 different solutions and compare them or to show to coworkers in video conference and demo them, then use branches

Comment: @kla yes, that sounds like a perfect use case for branches :)

Answer (score 1):

[after running `git stash apply`]

> Now, can I [run] `git stash apply` [again] to go back to the "clean" state?

No:

```
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: b0c09ab879 The eleve
nth (aka "ort") batch
$ git stash apply
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   Makefile

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git stash apply
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        Makefile
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

But there's no real need, because `git stash` ended by running `git reset --hard` to *get* you to the "clean" state you had when you then ran `git stash apply`.  So you can just run it again:

```
$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at b0c09ab879 The eleventh (aka "ort") batch
$ git stash drop
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (87dcb9a8bbdbfd1f7a92f330439f06f0accd3263)
```

(I dropped this stash since I had no further use for it at this point).

As [iBug notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67166183/how-can-we-git-stash-apply-to-move-between-all-states-of-the-repo#comment118722349_67166183), `git checkout -f HEAD` will work as well for this case.

It's worth noting here that all `git stash` does is *make commits*.

The commits that `git stash` makes are slightly special in two ways:

- They're shaped like a merge.  This is just for convenience in the `git stash` code itself, and it has a negative side effect: if you try to look at the stash commits, they look weird, because Git treats them *as if* they were merges.  They *are* merges, in a technical sense: the commit to which each stash ref entry points is a *merge commit*.  It's just not the kind of merge commit *you* would normally make, which misleads the Git commit-showing tools.
- They are on *no* branch.  Since they're not on any branch, there's no temptation to think of them as "the `master`-branch stash" or "the `develop`-branch stash".  A stash commit-clump is just "a stash", `stash@{number}`.

That first bit of special-ness—having the `W` commit in a two or three commit group that represents a stash, take the form of a *merge* commit—is, if anything, just a drawback, as far as stash-users are concerned.  Mostly, users don't look at all, but if they *do* look, Git itself gets weird and squirrelly with them.

That second bit of special-ness ... well, it might have some value to some people, but once you get used to Git, it has no real value one way or another.  Branches in Git are cheap and making a branch to hold one temporary commit is just fine.  Do that and don't worry about it, and don't bother with `git stash`.